# Does the frequency of a organ pipe changes with its diameter? Explain

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, resonance

I am confused a bit does the frequency of a organ pipe have relation with its diameter or not.

Comment: Not only in diameter but also length of the pipe.

Comment: In a physicist's approximation no, it doesn't.  In real life pipe diameter matters both for pitch and tone, because the zeroth-order physicist's approximation is not good enough when tuning matters to fractions of a Hz (1/10Hz perhaps in a frequency of (say) 440Hz, so .02%): real-life organ pipe design is a really complicated business, as is getting the wretched things in tune!

Answer (score 7):

The effective length of an organ pipe is larger than its physical length by an amount called the [end correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_correction) which for every open end is approximately 0.3 $\times$ diameter of the organ pipe.
So two organ pipes of the same length but different diameters will have different resonant frequencies the one with the larger diameter being lower in frequency.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think the frequency changes. Although the frequency is inversely proportional to the diameter $d$, as end correction, $e=(L + 0.3 d)$, we cannot neglect the change in its volume. When we simplify the normal equation, the diameter $d$ having a degree of $1$ comes in the numerator. Thus the change in diameter should cancel out each other when all other physical properties of the pipe are kept constant.

But I am not sure if my answer is correct. It is just my opinion.